# Ckeditor find and select text

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

What I want to do is create a selection on a word (similar to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on chrome),

I'm at this point

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var sel = editor.getSelection();
var element = sel.getStartElement();
var find = '[valor]';
var ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges();
var startIndex = element.getHtml().indexOf(find);
if (startIndex != -1) {
    ranges[0].setStart(element.getFirst(), startIndex);
    ranges[0].setEnd(element.getFirst(), startIndex + find.length);
    sel.selectRanges([ranges[0]]);
}
```

this works great it has only 1 problem. It only selects the text on the line I'm on, I want it to find the first occurrence on all the ckeditor text

Comment: Well you are finding it only once here element.getHtml().indexOf(find); to find all occurences this has to be in a loop and indexOf() should take another argument which will be the previous index.

Comment: i only want to find the first, the problem of this is it only work if i have the focus on a node that contains that word, and idk how to get all the textnodes

Comment: ok So do you want to find the first occurence in a selected text range, where the selection spans to different text nodes?

Comment: yes, i want it to find and select the first ocurrence on all the text of ckeditor, and the ckeditor divides every line in a diferent node, i have my problem there, that code only finds the text on the line im currently on (the node who has the focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can resolve this, all i need to do was get all the textnodes from the editor then search the word on the nodes and put them in an array something like this:

```
for ( i = textNodes.length; i--; ) {
text = textNodes[ i ];
index = text.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf( wordtosearch );

if ( index > -1 ) {

while (index > -1) {

    range = editor.createRange();
    range.setStart( text, index );
    range.setEnd( text, index + wordtosearch.length); 
    ranges.push( range );

    index= text.getText().indexOf( wordtosearch , index+wordtosearch.length );
}
}

}
```